# How can an extension obtain remote URL of file in currently connected remote server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I'm writing an extension targeted for VSCode Remote environment.
In this setup, one extension (UI extension) runs in client and another (workspace extension) runs in remote server.

Now, here's a question - is there any way to generate an URL that can be used by UI extension to access file on the server?

I know I can use `vscode-remote://ssh-remote+<hostname>/file/on/server` syntax to express this type of remote URL, but the issue here is that I cannot find any way for extension to discover one. Using vscode.Uri.file() API only generates `file:` URL, which is meaningless for UI extension running in client environment.

Since `vscode-remote:` scheme is fixed and `ssh-remote` part can be extracted from `vscode.env.remoteName` variable, the last piece I need is the hostname that was used to open current VSCode Remote session. Is there any API/variable to discover this?